# Viewing feature service view in Collector?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I have created a hosted feature service view in arcgis online and I have added this to a webmap. Editing is enabled on the hosted feature service view.

Should I be able to edit and view this on collector?

Comment: You should be able to. Can you give a bit more detail what you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Check out this story map that shows you the workflow and setup for views.

http://www.arcgis.com/apps/Cascade/index.html?appid=1884d94a00074098add274c84c8209e2